# Algebraic Topology self-study/prerequisites

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, computational-mathematics

I am a computer science student who, by nature of my major, am disallowed from taking all the of the math needed to get to algebraic topology for credit as an undergrad(there are a limited amount of credits I can take, and those credits will be eaten up by computer science classes at my university). Despite this I would like to build a path to understanding algebraic topology in my free time. There have been a lot of insights and inspirations from algebraic topology in my field in recent years and I see it as a good branch of mathematics to know generally for solving problems in computer science(proof writing, abstract thinking, etc).

I am finishing multivariate calculus, which covers some areas of elementary analysis, this fall alongside linear algebra. I have been doing linear algebra for a while now as I tutor it already and use a lot of it in my personal work/self study. I've also already done differential equations and numerical methods.

What will I need to ramp up to algebraic topology and is computational algebraic topology just an application of the theory? I noticed that [Michael Robinson at American University posted his class online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA1FFtTGAfw&list=PLSekr_gm4hWLRNHB5-sbajyUzN5tLOZmx) and I plan to watch that lecture or Norman Wildbergers once I get to the point to be able to do problems in algebraic topology.

I noticed that Michael just requires Calculus and Linear Algebra for his course but others on here seem to think an understanding of Groups is also necessary. How necessary are groups?

Comment: Unless the course you plan on reading has an introduction to group theory embedded, you **will** need to have at least a basic understanding of group theory before taking a course in algebraic topology. The whole point of algebraic topology is to assign algebraic objects (groups/rings/vector spaces/etc.) to topological spaces. It also would be helpful (some may say necessary) to have a grounding in point-set topology before starting algebraic topology.

Comment: The book http://www.groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html starts with the beginnings of point set topology and develops that in a geometric way for continuing in algebraic topology. There is no homology theory.

Comment: So I looked into it and most of the applications covered in the Michael Robinson course are from homology. Does this still require you to assign algebraic objects to topological spaces?